# gnu scientific library (GSL) cubic polynomial discrepancy in results

Tags: c++, polynomial-math, gsl, wolframalpha, polynomial-approximations

The [**GSL** polynomial solver](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Cubic-Equations.html) gives me an incorrect result. I have attempted to solve the following polynomial using **GSL cubic polynomial solver**:

x^3-1.96848e20 x^2+9.07605e28 x+9.07605e28 = 0

On **Wolframalpha** the **[results](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3-1.96848e20x%5E2%2B9.07605e28x%2B9.07605e28%3D%3D0)** are:

- -1
- 4.61069e+8
- 1.96848e+20

In **my program** the **results** are:

- 2.30531e+08
- 2.30531e+08
- 1.96848e+20

The **code** I used:

```
   #include <iostream>
    #include <gsl/gsl_poly.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {
      double result[3]={0,0,0};
      gsl_poly_solve_cubic(-1.96848e20,9.07605e28,9.07605e28, &result[0], &result[1], &result[2]);
      cout << result[0] << endl;
      cout << result[1] << endl;
      cout << result[2] << endl;
      return 0;
    }
```

What could be wrong?

Edit: Actually, Wolframalpha is also giving weird answers

Update: Both Wolframalpha is wrong (a bit closer to the right answer) and my code is wrong.

Here's the same solution in Python (Numpy library)

```
In [11]: np.roots(p)
Out[11]: array([  1.96848000e+20,   4.61068948e+08,  -9.99999998e-01])
```

Comment: It seems that jenkins-traub polynomial roots algorithm gives more accurate results, whereas the GSL cubic polynomial root gives rounded answers. In this case the order of the answers are around -1 ~ 2e20, which might give hint why the GSL algorithm fails. The Jenkins-Traub solver seems to give more accurate answers in this case.

Comment: No, there is no rounding involved in the GSL routine, only a numerically unstable case detection method that falsely concludes for a double root. Avoiding that branch would have resulted in the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The numerical method used in GSL is not accurate enough in this case.

Use e.g. [Jenkins-Traub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins%E2%80%93Traub_algorithm) algorithm (code [here](http://www.crbond.com/download/misc/rpoly.cpp))